# Angular routing failed

Tags: angular

Builded a basic webpage using angular cli version 8.3.

issue is as follows

eg:
[www.domainname.com](http://www.domainname.com) is working

[www.domainname.com/basicprinciples](http://www.domainname.com/basicprinciples) will work, if we go through the main page

but will not work, if we directly visit [www.domainname.com/basicprinciples](http://www.domainname.com/basicprinciples) by manually typing the link. The issue also happens with refresh.

I used sidenav angular material design and the content for all pages are loaded inside the sidenav content area. The content divs are loaded by using routerlink and ngif statement both inside app-main-nav component. And from basicprinciple component nothing but loading the app-main-nav component.

```
 <mat-nav-list>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/home" routerLinkActive="active">Home</a>
  <a mat-list-item routerLink="/basicprinciples" routerLinkActive="active">Basic Principles</a>
 </mat-nav-list>
```

and ngif inside the content area as follows

```
 <div *ngIf="router.isActive('/basicprinciples')">
        <div layout = "row" layout-xs = "column">
          <div flex class = "box">
                <h1 style="color:black;text-align:left;">Basic Principles</h1>

              page content here........

          </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

and app-routing as follows

```
const routes: Routes = [

{path:'' , component:HomeComponent},
{path:'home' , component:HomeComponent},
{path :'basicprinciples',component:BasicprinciplesComponent},
{path :'vpk',component:VpkComponent},
{path :'panchakoshas',component:PanchakoshasComponent},
{path :'detox',component:DetoxComponent},
{path :'btd',component:BtdComponent},
{path :'kbt',component:KbtComponent},
{path :'kmt',component:KmtComponent},
{path :'behindtheertham',component:BehindtheerthamComponent},
{path :'consultation',component:ConsultationComponent},
{path :'sptreatments',component:SptreatmentsComponent},
{path :'contact',component:ContactComponent},

 ];
```

Dont know, if i am on the right path.  Guide me if i am wrong. hope my question is clear.
Help appreciated.

Comment: Which location strategy are you using?

Comment: @ElegantCoder : PathLocationStrategy

Answer (score 1):

I think your web server thinks its a folder and can't locate the folder. Either configure your server accordingly or you can turn on hash routing.

```
const config: ExtraOptions = {
  useHash: true,
};

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, config)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
}
```

Comment: yes thanks it worked, but there appear a #mark like www.domainname.com/#/basicprinciples .. anyway to avoid that #mark